# Check email exist with php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to mysqli i wanted to check if email already exists in database with php and mysqli

Here is what i have done so far:

ini.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'connect.php';
include 'user.func.php'; 
?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');
if($con->connect_errno > 0){
die('Sorry, We\'re experiencing some connection problems.'); 
}
```

?>

register.php

```
<?php
include 'ini.php';
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<p>Username:<br/><input type="text" name="reg_name" maxlength="50"  ></p>
<p>Email:<br/><input type="text" name="reg_email" size="35" maxlength="50"  ></p>
<p>Password:<br/><input type="password" name="reg_password" maxlength="50" ></p>
<p>Re-type Password:<br/><input type="password" name="reg_re_password" maxlength="20"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Register" ></p>
</form>

<?php
include 'validate.php';
?>
```

validate.php

```
<?php
if(isset ( $_POST['reg_name'],$_POST['reg_email'], $_POST['reg_password'] )) {

$errors = array();
$name = $_POST['reg_name'];
$email = $_POST['reg_email'];
$password = $_POST['reg_password'];
$re_password = $_POST['reg_re_password'];
if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($re_password)){
$errors[] = 'All fields are required';
 } else {

if(strlen($name) > 50 || strlen($email) > 50 || strlen($password) > 50) {
 $errors[] = 'One or more field has too long Characters';
}

if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE && $password !== $re_password){
$errors[] = 'Enter valid email address and password do not match';
}else{

if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
$errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}

if($password !== $re_password){
$errors[] = 'Both passwords do not match';
}
if(user_exists($email) > 0){
$errors[] = 'That email is already been registered';
}

}

}

if (!empty($errors)) {
foreach ($errors as $errors) {
    echo '<strong>',$errors,'</srtong><br />';
}
}else{
echo 'Registered';
}
}
```

?>
user.func.php

```
<?php    
function user_exists($email) {

$con = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

if ($stmt->execute()) {
return $stmt->num_rows;
}
return false;
}
?>
```

This code shows all the other errors but doesn't check if the email exist. Instead it shows registered even when i enter email that is already in database.

I have database named 'test'. And table 'users' with columns user_id, username, email and password.

Can anyone tell how to code mysqli query for this?

I used this code in mysql

```
function user_exists($email) {
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM 'users' WHERE 'email'='$email'");
return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true :false;
}
```

Comment: `return $stmt->num_rows` returns an integer, not a strict `true`/`false`. Consider Yogesh's answer.

Comment: Extending from comments in Yogesh's answer: Do you have a MySQLi connection working in your program? Where did you declare it?

Comment: yes the connection is working

Comment: **Where** did you declare the connect? Global space?

Comment: in the ini.php i have included connect.php

Comment: And how did you declare the connection object? What's the variable name, and is it accessible in global space?

Comment: Your edited version at this point seems fine, except that you don't have to `$con=new mysqli(...);` in `user_exists`. Just `global $con;` can work.

Comment: @Passerby it doesnt work thats what i am saying

Comment: its says registered and i want it to say That email is already been registered

Comment: You forgot to `$stmt->store_result()` at this version.

Answer (score 1):

Use this condition, because you are returning the number of rows from your query.

```
if(user_exits($register_email) > 0){
```

**Edit**

```
function user_exists($email) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("host", "my_user", "my_password", "your_db");
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM users WHERE email = ?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        return $stmt->num_rows;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Kishore Should `user_exits($register_email)` be `user_exists($email)`?

Comment: @Kishore user_exi **S** ts, not user_exits. Is that a typo?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar i get these two errors      Notice: Use of undefined constant USER_TABLE - assumed 'USER_TABLE' in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\reg_test\user.func.php on line 19

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\reg_test\user.func.php on line 21

Comment: @Kishore is `USER_TABLE` defined using `define()`?

Comment: @Kishore you can't use `$this` without using `class`. In your code it should be your `mysqli` object.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar can you tell briefly what should i do?

Comment: @Kishore Despite that error, you function will still not work, because you're querying `COUNT(*)`, which will always return one row (the total count), so `$stmt->num_rows` will always be `1`, even if the count is `0`. You'll either need to get the result and check the value, or query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE email=?`.

Comment: @Passerby i changed my query as you said and what should i do

Comment: @YogeshSuthar it says registered but i already have that email address in database

Comment: @Kishore Try some debugging like what `user_exists` returns when email is present and when not.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar i have added the code i used in mysql in my question

Comment: @Passerby help for this query

Answer (score 1):

I could tell how to do it with [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
<?php
function user_exists($email) {
    $query = "SELECT 1 FROM " . USER_TABLE . " WHERE email = ?";
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array($email));
    return (bool)$stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

Though I see no point in strict checking

```
if(user_exits($register_email))
```

would be more than enough

Also, I don't understand where did you get that `$register_email` variable. Do you have error reporting on?

By the way, you need an established PDO connection for this. This code won't work with mysqli

Comment: It is $email not $register_email i changed it but no result

Comment: it's because you are using mysqli, not PDO. And don't have error reporting on

Comment: it shows errors if no fields are filled but doesnt check email exists

Comment: That's what you did wrong. It should be not 0 but E_ALL and  in php.ini it have to be `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Comment: i dont want the code to show NOTICE or FATAL ERROR it needs to check the database and say "That email is already been registered".

Comment: if you don't want to **show** it, set `display_errors = 0` instead. But while you are the only user of the site, you have to see errors. otherwise you will be unable to make your code work at all. So, set both `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = 1` for a while. When your site goes live, change it to `display_errors = 0` and `log_errors = 1`. But `error_reporting` have to be **always** E_ALL